# Forcing evaluation of ArgMax

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, evaluation, version-6

How to force evaluation of `ArgMax` before its output gets used in `Solve`? 
Background: I'm trying to solve for the Nash equilibrium in various games using Mathematica. As a minimal example, I tried a Cournot competition game that I can solve by hand. It should be simple: for each of two players use `ArgMax` to find the optimal action given some conjectured action by the other player, then equate the chosen action to the conjectured action for each player and use Solve to find the equilibrium actions. The code I tried is

```
$Assumptions = {p, qa, qb, qachosen, qbchosen} >= 0
p[qa_, qb_] := 1 - qa - qb
qachosen[qb_] = ArgMax[qa*p[qa, qb], qa]
qbchosen[qa_] = ArgMax[qb*p[qa, qb], qb]
Solve[{qachosen[qb] == qa, qbchosen[qa] == qb}, {qa, qb}]
```

The output gives the warning

> Solve::dinv: "The expression ArgMax[qa (1-qa-qb),qa] involves unknowns in more than one argument, so inverse functions cannot be used"

and does not give the answer. 
In the above example, ideally `qachosen` would become the function `(1-qb)/2`, `qbchosen` would be `(1-qa)/2` and the Solve output would be `qa=1/3, qb=1/3`. It seems forcing evaluation of `ArgMax` before applying `Solve` should do the trick, but `Evaluate[Argmax[...]]` returned the same thing as `ArgMax[...]`.

Comment: You are using `=` where you want `:=`, but I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: It works for me without error (8.0.4 linux) It's possible some old definitions are used try `Clear[p,qa,qb,qachosen,qbchosen]` and then run the code again

Comment: Same error occurs with ´:=´ and after using ´Clear´. I'm using Mathematica 6 with Windows XP.

Comment: It's ` to escape code and not ´ (notice they are pointing different ways)

Comment: Does `ArgMax[qa (1-qa-qb),qa]` return `(1 - qb)/2` or does it remain unevaluated?

Comment: Remains unevaluated.

Comment: [Perhaps ArgMax was introduced in version 7](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn70.html) Does `qa /. Last@Maximize[qa (1 - qa - qb), qa]` give anything useful? If it does you can define `ArgMax` as `Clear@ArgMax;
Attributes[ArgMax] = {HoldAll};
ArgMax[expr_, vars_] := vars /. Last@Maximize[expr, vars]`

Comment: Success! Thank you, the following does it:    `Clear[p, qa, qb, qachosen, qbchosen]
$Assumptions = {p, qa, qb, qachosen, qbchosen} >= 0
p[qa_, qb_] := 1 - qa - qb
qa[qb_] = qa /. Last@Maximize[qa*p[qa, qb], qa]
qb[qa_] = qb /. Last@Maximize[qb*p[qa, qb], qb]
Solve[{qa[qb] == qa, qb[qa] == qb}, {qa, qb}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArgMax` was introduced in version 7, but version 6 has `Maximize` so you can define `ArgMax` as:

```
Clear@ArgMax;
Attributes[ArgMax] = {HoldAll};
ArgMax[expr_, vars_, domain___] := vars /. Last@Maximize[expr, vars, domain]
```

Taken from documentation which says:

> `ArgMax[...,vars,...`] is effectively equivalent to `vars/.Last[Maximize[...,vars,...]`.